# Form Bigrams in Pandas DataFrame not only words next to each other

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, n-gram

I have a huge but simple Pandas DataFrame.
rows look like this:

```
index   Text
1   This is a sample text
2   I am a test text
3   this is a test
```

I want to create **bigrams** for every row. What i did:

```
from nltk.collocations import *

def create_bigram(word_list):
    finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(word_list)
    return finder.ngram_fd.items()

test_str = "This is a sample text".split()
create_bigram(test_str)
```

Which returns:

```
[(('This', 'is'), 1),
 (('is', 'a'), 1),
 (('a', 'sample'), 1),
 (('sample', 'text'), 1)]
```

But I want to register all appearances of every words in every row, not only of words next to each other.

Like this:

```
index   Bigrams
1   (this, is), (this, a), (this, sample), (this, text), (is, a), (is, sample), (is, text)...
```

and so on...

I want this to be able to see how often words appear together in one DataFrame row.

Is there some sort of default function from nltk ( or other nlp libs) to do this or do I have to do this on my own?

I am not able to find anything other than bigrams or trigrams oder ngrams, but they all only do calculations regarding their direct neighbours, am I right?

And it's quite time consuming to do a simple nested for loop for over 300,000 rows of longer text than "This is a sample text", to calculate every appearance...

Edit:
Somehow I feel like to miss the obvious, but I am not able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
from itertools import permutations
import pandas as pd


def create_bigram(word_list):
    split_test_str = word_list.split()
    perms = [','.join(element) for element in permutations(split_test_str, 2)]   
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[perms])
    print(df)


test_str = 'This is a sample text'
create_bigram(test_str)
```

The easiest way is to create a permutation of your string to get the desired result.

This is possible with the function permutation of itertools.
You can read more about the function on https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: @XEmporea did it help you?